# Regex to match and use a name between two delimiting words

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I use this code to save each section from the individual documents from a Mailings generated document

```
Sub BreakOnSection()
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

   'A mail merge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

'Note: If a document does not end with a section break,
'substitute the following line of code for the one above:
'For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard.
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add ("C:\Users\simaco\Desktop\New folder (4)\new.dotx")
      Selection.Paste

   ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\simaco\Desktop\New folder (4)"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1

    With ActiveDocument
    Set r = .GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast)
    Set r = .Range(r.Start - 1, .Characters.Count)
    r.Delete
    End With


     ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & DocNum & ".doc"
     ActiveDocument.Close
      ' Move the selection to the next section in the document.
     Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

I want to save each page with the `John Doe` name which is found in the document between two delimiting words like this:

```
Employee John Doe that etc etc.
```

How can I match `John Doe`in the `ActiveDocument`between the two words (`Employee` and `that`) using a regular expression and then be able to use the found string like `ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Doc" & FoundString & ".doc"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?<=Employee\s)([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\s?that)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/76)

Comment: John  Doe van be any name

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Can you change the regex to JavaScript/JScript flavor?